# Fast growing autoincerment key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have cluster with 3 mysql servers, and one table that often updates. The queries in this table like:

```
INSERT INTO tablename
.... 400 records
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
...
```

And autoincremented primary key in this table is growing very fast. The id skip a few hundred records, somitimes even more than 400.

How can i fix it? I still need mass query because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will increase the AUTO_INCREMENT value regardless if a row was inserted or not. This is normal behavior.

You need to provide more information as to **how** you are performing these inserts if you want a better answer.